# Regex optional group parsing

Tags: regex

Been fiddling with this for hours...

I'm trying to parse error messages of this form:

```
[error]  C:\Me\MyPath\myFile.scala:18:22: not found: value getaa
```

I can do this fine with the following regex:

```
\[(error|warn)\]\s+(.+):(\d+):(?:\d+:)\s+(.+)$
```

Which correctly produces groups:

```
error
C:\Me\MyPath\myFile.scala
18
not found: value getaa
```

But to make this robust, I need to make the `22:` part optional (since some versions of the scala compiler don't output column number). In other words, it needs to produce the same groups as above for this string too:

```
[error]  C:\Me\MyPath\myFile.scala:18: not found: value getaa
```

I've tried putting a question mark after the optional group, but that doesn't work - it messes up the original groups. I assume there's some stuff about lazy vs greedy that I'm not understanding. [Here is a working sample](https://regex101.com/r/L3JUok/1/) on regex101. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add two question marks:

```
\[(error|warn)\]\s+(.+?):(\d+):(?:\d+:)?\s+(.+)$
                      ^                ^
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ck9MKM/1/)

The `.+?` will match any 1+ chars other than line break chars *as few as possible*, and will thus match up to the first occurrence of the subpatterns to follow. The second `?` will make `(?:\d+:)` group optional.

**Full pattern details**

- `\[`  - a `[`
- `(error|warn)` - one of the two substrings (`error` or `warn`)
- `\]` - or just `]` - a single `]` char
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(.+?)` - any 1+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible, up to the first...
- `:` - a colon
- `(\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits
- `:` - a colon
- `(?:\d+:)?` - a non-capturing group matching 1+ digits and a colon after them 1 or 0 times
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(.+)` - Group 3: the rest of the line
- `$` - end of string (note that it is not necessary here since `.+` is a greedy subpattern)

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks, and very clear explanation.

Answer (score 4):

You guessed correctly. It's due to the greediness of `.+`. It eats up the entire input text then tries to backtrack by giving up one character at a time until the end of the pattern matches.

As a rule of thumb, you should *never* write `.+` unless you *explicitly* want to go to the end of the input.

Here's the fixed pattern:

```
^\[(error|warn)\]\s+(.+?):(\d+):(?:(\d+):)?\s+(.+)$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/L3JUok/2)

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks. Your rule of thumb not to use .+ makes a lot of sense now. Below answer has a bit more detail but wish I could accept both.